# framework7 slider range do not working in google chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, html-framework-7

in framework7 slider range do not working in google chrome browser and working in another browser

[image]

code:

```
 <div class="item-content">
                  <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-form-settings"></i></div>
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="item-title label">Slider</div>
                    <div class="item-input">
                      <div class="range-slider">
                        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="0.1">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code you posted this way:

```
<div class="list-block">
  <ul>
    <li class="row">
      YOUR CODE HERE
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Let me know if this works!